# DB2 error while loading shared libraries

Tags: db2

When i execute 'db2stop' or 'db2start' command on Centos finally 6.4 (Final). I am getting error as follows:

```
> error while loading shared libraries: libnuma.so.1: cannot open shared
> object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried as follows commands but it didn't work..

```
# yum install compat-libstdc++-33
# yum install libaio
```

waiting your solutions.

Answer (score 4):

I executed the following command and I got it: apt-get install numactl

Answer (score 0):

And also if you get following error

DBT3514W  The db2prereqcheck utility failed to find the following 32-bit library file: "/lib/libpam.so*"
then execute

sudo yum install pam.i686